# Mac OS Sierra with Macports, when changing " ~/.profile " file, i'm losing colors in my terminal (export PATH=...)

Tags: macos, terminal, macports, macos-sierra, bash

I know maybe this is a ridiculous question but i have many folders and executable files in terminal, so i need colors.
This is my question;

- When i export some PATH file like this;

  ```
    export PATH=/opt/local/libexec/gnubin/:$progFiles/****/*****/*****/bin:$PATH
  ```

  I'm losing the colors in my terminal like when i enter a command like "ls" it can't show the colors for the folders and executables etc. all of them are just white. When i close this export command line with # i can see the colors again like a magic. Any help will be appreciated.
          Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably happens because you prepend `/opt/local/libexec/gnubin` to `$PATH` and have the `coreutils` port installed. The `coreutils` port installs copies of the usual GNU utilities, among them `ls`, into `/opt/local/bin`, but prepends them with a `g` for GNU.

Additionally, the `coreutils` port provides the unprefixed versions in `/opt/local/libexec/gnubin`. So when you put that first in your `$PATH`, typing `ls` will no longer use macOS' BSD ls at `/bin/ls`, but GNU's ls from `/opt/local/libexec/gnubin/ls`, which only prints colors if you call it with `--colors=auto` (which is easily achieved by an alias).

When you type `/bin/ls`, you'll likely get the output you are used to.

Comment: Yes, this might be the solution but i had no experience with this profile or bashrc kind of files. That's why i'm asking for an alias to try if its working or not...

Comment: You didn't ask for an alias in your original question, and frankly, I don't know what kind of alias you would want here…

Comment: Nevermind, just  alias ls='ls --color=auto' worked for me. Thank you for your answers...